# Quadratic Sieve: Target value in computing sum of logarithms

Tags: prime-factorization

I've been reading Scott Contini's [thesis](http://www.crypto-world.com/documents/contini_siqs.pdf) that implements the quadratic sieve.

In the MPQS, Figure 2.2 Trial Division Stage, why is the target value $\log(M\sqrt{N})$ minus a small error term? Shouldn't the target value depend on $x$? I'm worried that, when the absolute value of $x$ is small, a smooth $g(x)$ will be missed because the sum of the logarithms is less than the target.

I understand that the essence of the sieving procedure is to trade a little slop for speed, but small values of $x$ are exactly the place where smooth $g(x)$ are most likely to be found, and that seems like a bad place to accept some slop.